# Rails 3 session variable not deleting right away using cache storage in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, session-variables, session-cookies

I am using the cache store for session storage in Rails 3. In production deleting a session variable doesn't seem to be reflected until the request has completed.  That makes sense for cookie storage, but not for cache storage. Also, this isn't a problem in staging which makes me think it's a config issue. I'm not sure what config parameter would cause this, though.

Any ideas?

Here's the action code. The variable is cleared because the user can add more things to the session while the first request is being processed, but the session variable can't overlap between requests.

```
id_list = session[:batch_select_ids]
#Clear the session variable
session.delete(:batch_select_ids)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Some code will be helpful.

Comment: Are you expecting to to see changes reflected immediately when another (overlapping) request is made?

Comment: I am, yes. It happens on staging but not in production. It could be my configs but I am yet to figure out which config that would be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is we're using unicorn on staging and phusion passenger on production. Not a smart setup, I know.

Thanks again.